# Require js didn't load my Js in custom module

Tags: addtocart, requirejs

I'm working on a custom module for GTM.

The last part I facing issue is with require js.

I want to trigger a custom JS on `"add to cart"` click.

I made a `requirejs-config.js` file in `Vendorname/modulename/view/frontend`
with this :

```
alert("Hello");
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            "catalogAddToCart":    'Vendorname_modulename/js/customCatalogAddToCart'
        }
    }
};
```

If I clear cache deploy static content (with -f mode as I'm in developer mode) I got my alert.

But in my `Vendorname/modulename/view/frontend/web/js/customCatalogAddToCart.js`
I add

```
alert("world");
```

In the network panel, I didn't see the file `customCatalogAddToCart.js` and also didn't get the second Alert.

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: please remove `alert` from require js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please changes

> "catalogAddToCart":
>   'Vendorname_modulename/js/customCatalogAddToCart'

**to**

```
'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart':'Vendorname_modulename/js/customCatalogAddToCart'
```

try again.

Comment: Thanks It's better like that my script is loaded ! now I have to get all value needed (sku, productname,price) and i'm good.
Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Here is my situation:

I have following module:

```
app/code/Mymodule/Test/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
```

Here is the content of this file:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            catalogAddToCart: "Mymodule_Test/js/customCatalogAddToCart"
        }
    }
};
```

My Javascripts are at following location:

```
app/code/Mymodule/Test/view/frontend/web/js/customCatalogAddToCart.js
```

In the PHTML file:

```
app/code/Mymodule/Test/view/frontend/templates/home.phtml
```

I added the lines:

```
require(['jquery', 'catalogAddToCart'],function($){
    alert("world");
});
```